# php realtime output of console process

Tags: php, real-time, echo, popen, shell-exec

i want to run a command in console then 'echo' it via a log file. i wrote following code. but it doesnt work. if i put command direct in 'popen' it waits first the page load..
what can be done ?

```
shell_exec("nohup $cmd > out.log 2>&1");  

if( ($fp = popen("tail out.log" , "r")) ) { 
       while(  strpos($txt, "FINISH") == false){ 
        $txt = fread($fp, 1024); 
        echo $txt; 

        flush();
       }     
}
```

Comment: Command is a string, you are missing quotes.

Comment: i hve already, just wrote here wrong... now edited...

Comment: What is the actual `$cmd`?

Comment: '$cmd="/home/User/Slic3r/slic3r.pl $file"'